# MySQL syntax confusion - Merging together simple data for a graceful single-row insertion

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I am building a MySQL table to aggregate a set of particular information for a customer. Much of it I've assembled and filtered successfully with simple `INNER JOIN` commands on records with shared keys/columns, but the pivoting/transposing of the data, even being of a fixed size, is still causing me some syntax confusion for my query. The schema for this table `t_snapshots` can be seen as follows:

```
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)             | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment | 
| value_type  | tinyint(1) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| ch1_id      | varchar(20)         | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| ch1_val     | float               | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| ch2_id      | varchar(20)         | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| ch2_val     | float               | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| ch3_id      | varchar(20)         | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| ch3_val     | float               | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| ch4_id      | varchar(20)         | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| ch4_val     | float               | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| timestamp   | datetime            | NO   | MUL | current_timestamp() |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Simply put, I want to select the most recently updated value from `t_other_data0.ch[n]` to send to `t_snapshots.ch[n]_val` and select the most recently updated id from `t_id_pool.unit_id` for each unique `t_id_pool.channel_num` to send to `t_snapshots.ch[n]_id`. `t_id_pool.channel_num` is what correlates to the n value of columns `t_snapshots.ch[n]_val`:

--EDIT--: Ideally, sample data from source table `t_other_data0` that looks for the latest `unit_id` value from `t_id_pool` for `channel_num=1,2,3,4` and outputs to table `t_snapshots`:

Gather latest process data from `t_other_data0`. In this case, rows with `id` 5-8 are selected because they span all distinct `value_type` with the latest `timestamp`.:

```
Table: t_other_data0
+----+------+------+------+------+------------+---------------------+
| id | ch1  | ch2  | ch3  | ch4  | value_type | timestamp           |
+----+------+------+------+------+------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 1.65 | 3.25 | 1.98 | 2.17 |          1 | 2021-07-22 16:26:40 |
|  2 | 3.12 | 2.33 | 6.42 | 3.22 |          2 | 2021-07-22 16:26:40 |
|  3 | 2.22 | 2.24 | 3.34 | 1.17 |          3 | 2021-07-22 16:26:40 |
|  4 | 1.52 | 1.34 |  1.9 | 2.01 |          4 | 2021-07-22 16:26:40 |
|  5 |  3.2 | 3.21 | 5.42 | 2.13 |          1 | 2021-07-22 16:26:50 |
|  6 | 1.55 | 1.92 | 4.32 | 4.12 |          2 | 2021-07-22 16:26:50 |
|  7 | 2.31 | 1.93 | 2.36 |  3.4 |          3 | 2021-07-22 16:26:50 |
|  8 | 1.78 | 2.17 | 5.62 | 2.34 |          4 | 2021-07-22 16:26:50 |
+----+------+------+------+------+------------+---------------------+
```

Because these permanent channels change what temporary equipment they're tied to, we determine the current `unit_id` for each `channel_num` using latest `unit_id` from `t_id_pool`:

```
Table: t_id_pool
+----+---------------------+-------------+---------+
| id | timestamp           | channel_num | unit_id |
+----+---------------------+-------------+---------+
|  1 | 2021-07-22 09:39:09 |           1 | S4251   |
|  2 | 2021-07-22 09:38:09 |           2 | S3552   |
|  3 | 2021-07-22 09:38:09 |           3 | S0001   |
|  4 | 2021-07-22 09:38:09 |           4 | S1001   |
|  5 | 2021-07-22 09:39:10 |           1 | P5251   |
|  6 | 2021-07-22 09:38:10 |           2 | P4552   |
|  7 | 2021-07-22 09:38:10 |           3 | P1001   |
|  8 | 2021-07-22 09:38:10 |           4 | P2001
+----+---------------------+-------------+---------+
```

Output to `t_snapshots`:

```
Table: t_snapshots
+-----+---------------------+------------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| id  | timestamp           | value_type | ch1_id | ch1_val | ch2_id | ch2_val | ch3_id | ch3_val | ch4_id | ch4_val |
+-----+---------------------+------------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| 211 | 2021-07-14 16:26:50 |          1 | P5251  |     3.2 | P4552  |    3.21 | P1001  |    5.42 | P2001  |    2.13 |
| 212 | 2021-07-14 16:26:50 |          2 | P5251  |    1.55 | P4552  |    1.92 | P1001  |    4.32 | P2001  |    4.12 |
| 213 | 2021-07-14 16:26:50 |          3 | P5251  |    2.31 | P4552  |    1.93 | P1001  |    2.36 | P2001  |     3.4 |
+-----+---------------------+------------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Share us some example (fake) data from `t_id_pool` table.. Also with that example data, how would the expected result look like in the `SELECT` query.

Comment: @FaNo_FN Edits made to describe source tables and ideal output as requested

Comment: `id=4` is selected? Because it seems like it's not the latest `timestamp` for it. Also, I didn't see any of the `id=4` row data in the output.

Comment: I was wondering why the `t_other_data.id=8` was missing. I started [a fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3V7J1sBtGhb9SumxKwyBLr/1) but ran out of time.  [mariadb-10.4 dbfiddle<>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3) would have been better but its not running for me at the momement.

Comment: That's correct regarding id=4. In my example, I meant to say rows with id 5-8 are selected. I have corrected this, along with misspelt table names.

Comment: Additionally, I did only provide a transformed output for `value_type`=1,2,3 while the raw records indicated 4 different value types. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table `t_other_data0` seems to be a pivot table. Therefore, I think the first step is to un-pivot it then join it with `t_id_pool` table to get the latest `unit_id`, then re-pivot it again. Maybe a query like this can work:

```
SELECT 0 id, tod.timestamp, value_type,
       MAX(case when channel_num=1 THEN unit_id else 0 END) AS ch1_id,
       SUM(case when channel_num=1 then chan_val else 0 END) as ch1_val,
       MAX(CASE WHEN channel_num=2 THEN unit_id ELSE 0 END) AS ch2_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN channel_num=2 THEN chan_val ELSE 0 END) AS ch2_val,
       MAX(CASE WHEN channel_num=3 THEN unit_id ELSE 0 END) AS ch3_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN channel_num=3 THEN chan_val ELSE 0 END) AS ch3_val,
       MAX(CASE WHEN channel_num=4 THEN unit_id ELSE 0 END) AS ch4_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN channel_num=4 THEN chan_val ELSE 0 END) AS ch4_val
FROM   (SELECT value_type, ch1 AS chan_val, 1 AS chan_num, timestamp
        FROM   (SELECT *, Row_number() OVER (partition BY value_type ORDER BY id DESC) rn
                FROM t_other_data0) AS A
        WHERE  rn = 1 UNION ALL
        SELECT value_type, ch2, 2,
               timestamp
        FROM   (SELECT *, Row_number() OVER (partition BY value_type ORDER BY id DESC) rn
                FROM t_other_data0) AS A
        WHERE  rn = 1 UNION ALL
        SELECT value_type, ch3, 3,
               timestamp
        FROM   (SELECT *, Row_number() OVER (partition BY value_type ORDER BY id DESC) rn
                FROM t_other_data0) AS A
        WHERE  rn = 1 UNION ALL
        SELECT value_type, ch4, 4,
               timestamp
        FROM   (SELECT *, Row_number() OVER (partition BY value_type ORDER BY id DESC) rn
                FROM t_other_data0) AS A
        WHERE  rn = 1) AS tod
       JOIN (SELECT id, timestamp, channel_num, unit_id, 
                    Row_number() OVER (partition BY channel_num ORDER BY timestamp DESC) rn
             FROM t_id_pool) AS tip
         ON tod.chan_num = tip.channel_num AND tip.rn = 1
    GROUP BY tod.timestamp, value_type;
```

One of the functions being used here is `ROW_NUMBER()` with a purpose to assign row number `1` on the latest `value_type` and `channel_number` timestamps. As for table `t_other_data0`, I'm using `UNION ALL` and  there are 4 queries in total following the columns `ch1, ch2, ch3 & ch4`. Each of them I assign with a hardcoded `chan_num` according to which column I take.

I'm not sure about the column `id` there of what to populate but I assume that since the main purpose of the query is to `INSERT` into another table, then maybe the `id` column is auto increment.

Unfortunately dbfiddle.uk can't be use since yesterday so the fiddle here is for MySQL v8.0 instead of MariaDB 10.3. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xf1VmfYMbnGcabJS7dS6A1/1 . The result in the fiddle will have an extra row for `t_other_data.id=8` (mentioned by @danblack in the comment) and will not include `id=4` since your condition is *"Gather latest process data from t_other_table0"*. But judging from your expected output, it seems like you didn't include `id=4` so maybe there were some mistype in your description.

Comment: Great example. Thanks for taking the time to put all that in Fiddle and show the example. The syntax makes a little more sense to me now with the unions and joins to make this work. Seems to have transfered over well into MDB 10.3 as far as I can tell; have not tested execution times on my adaptation of this to the production data pool, but look forward to trying it out!

Comment: Only issue I'm seeming to have thus far is in a MySQL 5.7 environment (Amazon Aurora). Getting a 1064 near '(partition' but to my knowledge I assumed this was legal.

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL 5.7 doesn't support `ROW_NUMBER()`. There's a way to generate row numbers for older versions. Let me get back to you on that.

Comment: See this fiddle @user8585939 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7044825b1221db236c3d5e6f05da2318

Comment: Looking back on this, would you optimize this any way for really large data sets within `t_other_data0` (>10M lets say)?

Comment: I can try but I suggest that you post a new question. I can assure you that there are a lot of other capable, more experienced people in SO that can help you in figuring out the performance side of it. For me, I don't really have a lot of experience in performance tweaking, most of my work are not really "performance demanding" per se. Maybe someone can even suggest to you a more refined and efficient query.